# Accidentally added plastic to compost

Tags: compost

I'm new to composting, and about a week ago added cardboard packaging from freezer food (like an Eggo waffles box) - I shredded it up and mixed it into my compost bin. I've since learned that these boxes usually have a plastic coating to protect them from moisture and freezer burn.

How bad will this be for my compost, and is there anything that I can do about it short of handpicking each piece from the compost?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I wouldn't worry about it - when you use the compost, if you see any bits of plastic, I'd pick them out, but it's not going to make your compost toxic or prevent the composting process from taking place, nor is it going to poison anything you use the compost for. I probably don't need to say, though, it would be best not to do it again!

Answer (score 7):

I am relatively new like you to composting and end up putting things in the compost accidentally.  Once in a while when you are turning the pile or removing the compost, you will notice these things and I generally just take it out.  I don't believe it harms the process or the output so nothing to worry about.  Another tip I learned the hard way is to not put steps and twigs without shredding.  They take a long time to decompose and get in the way of being able to easily turn the pile.   Good luck with composting.  You are doing a great thing for the environment!